# WindowsMobile CAB file I can't change the appname!

Tags: visual-studio, mobile, windows-mobile, cab

I have a Windows mobile professional 6.1 application and I created a CAB file for that..when I am installing the cab in the phone in some place of installation I see a wrong app name which I don't even remember when and where I have setted it!

SO I checked  the _system.xml  file in the CAB archive and saw the problemetic line;

```
 <parm name="AppName" value="Wrong app name" />
```

But I couldnt find where can I change this wrong app name from inside the visual studio!!

I tried to edit the cab file but couldnt do that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the installer project. In the `Properties` window edit the `ProductName` property.

Comment: Tnx but I can't find ProductName property under Properties?

Comment: It's the last one (if sorting alphabetically A>Z)

Comment: Yeah I supposed to see a grid with properties when I click the properties but what I see is tabs named as "application" "Build" "Debug" "Settings".."Signing"

I can't open the correct properties grid.....

Comment: @jan - at the very least, you should accept a correct answer.   A comment saying 'thanks' is nice, but what most people want is an 'accept' and an upvote.